# SQL / BQ - Update app names from table using merge function

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I work with mobile app data and I have a table with app names that need to be cleaned up / replaced. For eg, "App V2" needs to be changed to "App". I was told to "Select all data except app and app_name (see below) from the table and then rewrite app name with the correct app name, then use a MERGE function to overwrite the table."  The table I have is session_data.

The columns I have are:

```
  date, 
  country,
  app_id,
  app_name,
  app,
  SUM(daily_active_users) AS daily_active_users
```

- Sample Data:
- Date: 2020-08-01
- Country: US
- app_id: 1234
- app_name: app v2
- app = app v2
- daily_active_users = 5

I haven't got a clue where to begin and I am turning to the Stack Overflow community. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thank you for your reply. What would you need specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating a BigQuery table can be costly affair. If you know all the values to be updates, you can do this by using a case statement while selecting the columns and then overwrite the same table (Kind of simulating the update)

Step 1

```
select date, 
  country,
  app_id,
  case when app_name = 'App V2' then 'App'
       when app_name = 'App V3' then 'App3'
       .
       .
       .
   end as app_name ,
  app,
  SUM(daily_active_users) AS daily_active_users
from session_data
```

Step 2
Now direct this output in temp table and then overwrite the `session_data` using all the data from stage table

Here you are simulating the update statement

Comment: Thank you Hemant! How would I write the merge function? I do not want to overwrite the entire table, just the records going forward, so I would have to add a date filter from 2020-08-10. Both tables have the same schema.